# SharePoint 2013 Set webpartZones in horizontal

Tags: 2013, page-layout, html

I need to set two webpartzones in Horzontal way (side by side) and the third zone at the bottom of these two Zones. I need help in getting the webpart zones aligned horizontally. I used Designer manager to add the snippets and created the html file
The extract of html file for the webpart zones is as follows

```
 <div data-name="WebPartZone">
<!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx"%>-->
<div xmlns:ie="ie">
    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="xxcdxcxcxcxcxcx" TabIndex="1" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Height="38%" LayoutOrientation="Horizontal" Width="42%" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical" Title="Zone1">-->
        <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
            <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
</div>
<!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
```

```
  <div data-name="WebPartZone">
<!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx"%>-->
<div xmlns:ie="ie">
    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="fddsdffdsfsdffaa" TabIndex="2" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Height="38%" LayoutOrientation="Horizontal" Padding="4" Width="42%" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" Title="Zone2">-->
        <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
            <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
</div>
<!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
```

```
  <div data-name="WebPartZone">
<!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx"%>-->
<div xmlns:ie="ie">
    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="dfdsaeeew323333" TabIndex="5" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Height="30%" LayoutOrientation="Vertical" Width="100%" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" Title="Zone 3">-->
        <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
            <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
</div>
<!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
```

Thanks
Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="float left">left WP zone here</div>
    <div class="float right">right WP zone here</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom< WP zone here/div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {width:600px; height:300px; position:relative;}
.float {background-color:black; height:300px; margin:0; padding:0; color:white;}
.left {background-color:blue; position:fixed; width:300px;}
.right {float:right; width:300px;}
.bottom {width:600px; height:300px; background-color:red;color:white}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8ph92xo/1/

Comment: Thank you Jussi for the response, I upped the response by 1. My question is when I specify LayoutOrientation="Horizontal", shouldn't that arrange them horizontally based on the width specified in zones.

Comment: Can you explain how is it not working?

Comment: It is working fine, but my question is, the msdn documentation says that, we can arrange the zones by specifying the LayoutOrientation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartzonebase.layoutorientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I was mistaken, The LayoutOrientation property concerns how Web Parts controls are laid out in a zone.